# why css not apply on anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I make a simple example of next js .I tried to apply `css` but it not apply on `anchor tag`.

Here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-pine-s8x7h?file=/styles.css

```
a {
  color: red;
}
```

I imported `styles.css` like that

```
import "../styles.css";
import Head from "next/head";
import React from "react";
import App from "next/app";

export default class TailwindApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <Head>
          {/* <link href="./a.css"  rel="stylesheet" /> */}
        </Head>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Feels like you went directly to the middle of some React tutorial... Missing the whole point. You don't have to render a `head` and some `link` tags within a component....

Comment: I am rendering `Component `

Comment: Yeah... That is something too. Naming a component `Component`... That is fun.

Comment: actually `it is a _app.js` to override default configuration .it's nextjs not properly react

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to import the css, otherwise it won't be loaded into the project.

`import '../styles.css';`

https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-mclaren-2djfw?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: thanks for answering . I already add `styles.css` in `_app.js` why it is not working

Comment: It looks like `_app.js` isn't included in the project - It's not being loaded. It's an excess file.

Comment: thanks for reply will `tree-shaking` will work here ?

Comment: Tree-shaking isn't really relevant here. I'm not really familiar with Next.js, but main thing would be to import _app.js into index, or something index imports.